# Pandas Data Re-arrangement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on sport.
The purpose is to record current eventdatetime and PreviousEventTime in a game. I have a sample dataset in the below link.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DUNrWPFwrkZHpq_KeA4rZCJ94sbpUEDI

In this file, there are 11 columns. the event are collected based on time.
For this re-arrange, i will be using the following columns
**gsm_ID**,**eventdatetime** columns

I want to create a new column **PreviousEventTime** that take n-1 row of the **eventdatetime** column.
That means for every **gsm_ID**, there will be the first **eventdatetime**.
The new column will represent the next event time as compared to the time column.

`gsm_ID        eventdatetime            PreviousEventTime`

> `2462794      08/11/2017 18:46         08/11/2017 18:45`
>
> `2462794      08/11/2017 18:49         08/11/2017 18:46`
>
> `2462794      08/11/2017 19:13         08/11/2017 18:49`
>
> `2462794      08/11/2017 19:31         08/11/2017 19:13`
>
> `2462794      08/11/2017 20:09         08/11/2017 19:31`
>
> `2462795      08/12/2017 17:39         08/12/2017 16:30`
>
> `2462795      08/12/2017 17:44         08/12/2017 17:39`

Above example is just for two games. You can differentiate by **gsm_id**. The for row at PreviousEventTime will always be **matchdatetime.**
I will have 100 over games. but the process will repeat as above-mentioned example.

Your advice would be much appreciated.
Regards,
zephyr

Answer (score 0):

First you have to load your dataset into pandas dataframe after we can use shift method.

```
last_val=df["Time"].iloc[-1]
df['second_eventime']=df['Time'].shift(-1)   #This will leave last column value as blank
df.iloc[-1, df.columns.get_loc('second_eventime')] = last_val #To Maintain the value at last row
```

Comment: Hi Kudi,Thanks for the help. It works as an extent.
IT arranged all time value to second event time. However, it was not in at one gsm_id. it means all the time are arranged without basing on gsm_id.
Thanks

Comment: @Zephyr Can you share an example.

Comment: I have edited the original post with an example.
Would appreciate much if you could advise.
Thanks