# Adding Time to date time

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

How do i add date and time? I have 3 columns as follow:

`kickoffDate =['8/6/2017','8/6/2017','8/6/2017']`
`kickoffTime = ['15:00:00','15:00:00','15:00:00']`
`time =['51:48:00','86:05:00','10:04']`

time in this case is mm:ss:00 format. 
i want to combine those three column to create a new column so called 'eventdatetime'.
what i expect for eventdatetime is
eventdatetime = [06-08-2017 15:51:48, 06-08-2017 16:26:05,06-08-2017 15:10:04].
How can i do this?
I am able to combine the first two by using following formula:

`DateTime1 =data['kickoffDate']+' '+ data ['kickoffTime']`

Can anyone advise?
Thanks

Comment: `df.['time']` is a typo.

Comment: @AmiTavory, Thanks for the reply. it was not the typos. i just edited my post.

Comment: You still have a typo :-)

Comment: @AmiTavory, My bad. it is not due to the typo. :(

Comment: What is the type of `time`? What does it signify: hours, minutes?

Comment: Hi Ami,
It is obj. but i converted to datetime format using the following code:
`data ['time']= pd.to_datetime(data['time'],format ='%d/%m/%Y/%H/%m/%s',errors ='coerce')`
it seems not converting to datetime format.

Comment: But what would be the meaning of adding two dates, then?

Comment: It would be much clearer if you'd write some sample inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: here is an example:
I will write an example. As mentioned above. I two columns (datetime and time). { datatime time 2018-01-31 20:00:00 00:11 } what i expect at new column "Event datetime" is 2018-01-31 20:00:11

Comment: time type at this moment is still object. I used the following code to convert to datetime 64[ns] format:
`data ['time']= pd.to_datetime(data.time,format ='%d/%m/%Y/%H/%m/%s',errors ='coerce')`
it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your edit here is what you need to do:

```
import pandas as pd

kickoffDate =['8/6/2017','8/6/2017','8/6/2017']
kickoffTime = ['15:00:00','15:00:00','15:00:00']
time = ['51:48:00','86:05:00','10:04']

df = pd.DataFrame({'kickoffDate': kickoffDate,
                   'kickoffTime': kickoffTime,
                   'time': time})

df['kickoffDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['kickoffDate'])
df['kickoffTime'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['kickoffTime'])
df['time'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_timedelta('{} minutes {} seconds'.format(*x.split(':')[:2])))

df['eventdatetime'] = df['kickoffDate'] + df['kickoffTime'] + df['time']

df
#  kickoffDate kickoffTime     time       eventdatetime
#0  2017-08-06    15:00:00 00:51:48 2017-08-06 15:51:48
#1  2017-08-06    15:00:00 01:26:05 2017-08-06 16:26:05
#2  2017-08-06    15:00:00 00:10:04 2017-08-06 15:10:04
```

Comment: I will write an example. As mentioned above. I two columns (datetime and time).
{
datatime                             time
2018-01-31 20:00:00         00:11 

}
what i expect at new column "Event datetime" is  2018-01-31 20:00:11

Comment: Dear Ami,
I have updated the question. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Thanks Zipa, Appreciate much. :)

Comment: I uploaded another issue :(. If you may have time and  want to help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50197214/pandas-data-re-arrangement